# spell checker with a twist

Tags: python, spell-checking

Have a quick question with regards to a spell checker but with a twist. effectively, its more vague than you're regular spell checker in the sense that it rather than correcting your words, it judges how correct you are based on how close one gets to the words. For instance, if one string is different from another based on two characters or less or less e.g. "hello and hallo", it will state "nearly there". Here is the code written below that I attempted.

```
def spell_checker(correct, guess):
    if guess==correct:
        print("Correct")
    if guess!=correct:
        for g in guess:
        for f in correct:
            if g!=f:
                print("nearly there")
            else:
                print("Wrong")
```

Obviously I realise this is quite a crude answer since it does not talk about the range of mistakes but to be honest, I could not find a way of incorporating the range of mistakes in word. Even when I looked at the response to nltk's answer, I did not know where to start.

The output for the answer when applying the "hello, hallo" example was as follows

Wrong
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
Wrong
Wrong
almost
almost
almost
Wrong
Wrong
almost
almost
almost
almost
almost
Wrong

I believe its almost going through each character and stating whether one character is similar to the other. Would really appreciate any help on this

Comment: Please focus your question on the specific technical problem you're asking about, not the application you're trying to create. If you haven't gotten to where you have a specific technical problem, you don't have a question suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Your output example is nothing short of miraculous. How could it ever print `almost`, while this word doesn't appear in your code? That said: you get so much output because it prints *something* for every `len(correct)*len(guess)`, which adds up quickly. "hello" and "hallo" outputs 25 results.

Comment: sorry man, the question is i know how to create it such that either the answers wrong or right. My specific technical issue is getting the "nearly there" function to work. I tried adding range function where i said if range(len(guess, correct) < 2, but that produced a technical error. Thats my specific problem, getting the "nearly there" function to work

Comment: sorry, i had to make changes since to be honest, this is copied from somewhere else.

Comment: the spelling bee online python question to be specific

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm completely stuck and don't know where to go from here

Comment: You should not immediately print something per comparison; keep a counter of the differences. I'm not sure how good a method is to compare *every* character to *every other* character of each word. Look up Levenshtein Distance for a better method. It will return the number of single edit changes that needs to be made to make `a` equal `b`; for your example, it's `1`.

Comment: (Which is how a spell checker works. It compares against a dictionary and suggests a list of words with the smallest distance. Your "twist" would be that it only needs to report that distance.)

Comment: its more a word comparer rather than a spell checker. I tried looking at nltks spell checker and that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are comparing *every* character in the first word with *every other* character in the other word. If you want to compare just characters in the same position, a very *very* simple way would be to `zip` the two words and count mismatched characters:

```
>>> a, b = "hello", "hallo"
>>> sum(x != y for x, y in zip(a, b))
1
```

But this will of course fail if the words do not have the same length. Also, it does not work well with missing or superfluous characters:

```
>>> a, b = "correct", "corect"
>>> sum(x != y for x, y in zip(a, b))
3
```

A better approach would be to calculate the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the two strings. If you do not want to implement the algorithm yourself, you could e.g. use [`difflib.ndiff`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff):

```
>>> list(difflib.ndiff(a, b))
['  c', '  o', '- r', '  r', '  e', '  c', '  t']
>>> sum(d[0] != " " for d in difflib.ndiff(a, b))
1
```

Note, however, that this will count replacements twice: Once for the deleted char, and once for the inserted char. You could fix this by e.g. not adding `1` if you get a `+` followed by a `-` or vice versa, which is left as an exercise to the interested reader.

Any way, just count the number of mismatched characters, and print `"almost"` if that number is small enough.

```
def spell_checker(correct, guess):
    if guess==correct:
        print("correct")
    elif sum(d[0] != " " for d in difflib.ndiff(correct, guess)) <= 2:
        print("almost")
    else:
        print("wrong")
```

Comment: tried using your first equation, but just produced almost repeatedly. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mohyaboulaydegaga Then you tried it the wrong way. My code does not even print anything. Let me expand on that a little... See my edit. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Really need to calculate the edit distance, otherwise you will get confusing variations of mismatch.  Consider matching "hello" to "hhello" and to "helloo" where a single deletion is all that is required for both to match, but naive counting will likely get very different results.

Comment: do you import difflib from somewhere as it says name is not defined

Comment: @mohyaboulaydegaga Yes, you have to `import difflib`, or if that's not possible, install it, e.g. using `pip` or `pip3`, or implement your own edit distance algorithm, which is a good exercise on its own.